# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: classTestEntity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, wildfly

I'm trying to get data using Spring JPA from two table in database:

[image]

And have the exception:

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.entity.Product
```

Product entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Product {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productService", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ProductService> productService;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ProductStatus.class, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_STATUS_ID")
    private ProductStatus status;
}
```

Repository is

```
public interface CaKeyRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {

}
```

Trying to load with findAll();

```
public HashMap<String, Key> loadProduct() throws Exception {
    List<Product> products = caKeyRepository.findAll();
```

Also I use the WildFly 12 application server.

Implementing to project with dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
        <artifactId>transactions-hibernate4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

All are provided

- Spring version - 4.3.10.RELEASE
- Spring data version - 1.11.6.RELEASE
- Hibernate-entitymanager version - 4.3.11.Final
- Hibernate-validator version - 5.1.3.Final
- Atomikos version - 4.0.4

Comment: Why is the `id` of `Product` of type `DECIMAL` in your d?

Answer (score 0):

Look like your entity is not scanned by hibernate.

If you configured JPA/Hibernate through persistence.xml:  `<class>com.entity.Product</class>`

if through Spring-ORM then in your [LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setPackagesToScan-java.lang.String...-) set the package in the `packagesToScan` method.